# Android password recovery with google

Tags: android, security

I want to implement password recovery in my android app like we have for various apps in which they have option of sending the password/resetting the password using Google/Facebook,etc.

It would be great if i got any guidance or a link explaining that.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Password/resetting using Google/Facebook,etc. is a logic where when you login into facebook from your app (assuming you have integrated facebook api) for every successful login an authentication token is generated into the app this token is unique for every user.

Now there are 2 scenarios:

> 1) First time login.
>
> 2) Already login into facebook from the app.

**First time login.**

Since the user is recovering password for the first time, Check if he is getting authentication token with the same email id he is registered into the app and facebook. If he gets the token it means he is a valid user into facebook and further you can match his details by getting all his profile info using facebook Graph API.

**Already login into facebook from the app.**

This scenario is when user is trying to login into facebook from app the second time , In this case you have to match his authentication token which you have got the first time.